# webpack, ignore size warning limit for a particular entrypoint

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

There are [multiple entrypoints](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/#object-syntax) in the webpack configuration of one of my projects.

At the moment there are two warnings about the size limit:

```
WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  entrypoint1 (282 KiB)
      entrypoint1.js
  entrypoint2 (247 KiB)
      entrypoint2.js
```

I find these warnings useful, but in some cases, I'd like to hide warnings for particular entrypoints, e.g. `entrypoint2` in this case.

Is it possible to ignore/hide size warnings for some entrypoints and show for all others?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for Performance assetFilter I believe.
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/performance/#performanceassetfilter

Webpack allows you to filter the assets you want to get performance warnings on:

```js
performance: {
  maxAssetSize: 170000,
  assetFilter: (asset) => {
    return asset.match('entrypoint1.js');
  }
}
```

This will only show performance warnings for entrypoint1.js, and of course you can build out the logic more complex in there to meet all kinds of conditions for environments, more files etc.

Comment: Thank you, Devin! This is exactly what I was looking for!